# Quantum Mechanical PDE Question

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I'm studying quantum mechanics and I'm considering the usual time-independent Schrödinger equation

\begin{equation*}
-\left(\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\right)\left(\nabla'\right)^{2}u_{E}(\mathbf{x}') + V(\mathbf{x}')u_{E}(\mathbf{x}') = Eu_{E}(\mathbf{x}')
\end{equation*}

where

\begin{equation*}
\left(\nabla '\right)^{2}
\end{equation*}

is the Laplacian. The textbook I'm reading goes on to mention that, upon imposing the boundary condition

\begin{equation*}
u_{E}(\mathbf{x}')\to 0\hspace{1pc}\mbox{ as }\hspace{1pc} \left|\mathbf{x}'\right|\to 0,
\end{equation*}

it is the case that the Schrödinger equation admits nontrivial solutions only for a discrete set of values of $E$. Although the text doesn't go on to mention it, I know this is due to the spectral theory of the Schrödinger PDE. I'd be grateful for references that discuss this.

*Edit*:I would mention that the textbook I'm using is the 3rd edition of *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai and Napolitano, just in case anyone wanted to know.

Comment: You'll need to specify the full domain of the problem to get a concrete answer. Also, what page of _Modern Quantum Mechanics_ is this on?

Comment: Never mind, it's on page 93, equation (2.188). You wrote the condition wrong, the condition is $$u_{E}(\mathbf{x}') \to 0 \ \text{as } \lvert \mathbf{x}' \rvert \to \color{red}{\infty}$$ This is required for the function to be square integrable and hence normalisable.